# How do I restore my mongodump backups to my newly sharded architecture? (Mongodb)

Tags: database, mongodb, backup

I have a directory of bson files (Results from my mongodump).

OK, so I just set up a new architecture for sharding MongoDB.  (2 replica sets--3 servers each, and also 1 config server and 1 mongos server).

I followed the tutorial. It was simple. Basic.

How do I load my database backup into this shard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use mongorestore and point it to the mongos server